# how to resolve a conflict between two Jar files that reside in separate Libraries within my project?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I wrote a project using Google Maps which imports classes from  **android.jar**
 and **maps.jar**, both of which sit in **Android Private Libraries** within by project's **Build Path**.

After receiving several

> "fix error in project before running it"

messages from **Android Launch** and not finding any errors in the code, I saw a warning in **Window>>Problems** that my project was lacking **JRE System files**, so I added **JRE System Library (jre.8.0_31)** to my project's **Build Path**.
I tried to run my project and got a **Console** error message

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
 Dx trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.class":
```

which according to

> /questions/2680827/“Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR

may result from a conflict between identical packages in different jar files. I checked and in my case there is a conflict between packages in **android.jar** (in my **Android Private Libraries**) and **rt.jar** (in the **JRE System Library**).

I don't know what to do:

- My project imports classes from **android.jar** so I can't get rid of that.

  **rt.jar** is part of **JRE System Library** which is probably needed.
- I have tried to extract packages from **android.jar** to include them by themselves in my **Build Path**, but couldn't find how to do this.

I have been stuck on this for days.Does anyone have any pointers, please?

Comment: share your log , is it Jar mis-match error ?

Comment: i don't think you have to add JRE to the build path, i don't have this anywhere in my projects.

Comment: @Yazan, what should I do about this warning

Comment: @Yazan,  point taken, Eclipse seems to have got rid of it anyway, if that makes sense.Thanks:)

Comment: @ZeeshanSaiyed   My JRE is gone but I am still getting this Console error message (nothing on my Logcat though).           [2015-01-28 13:14:37 - Maps] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2015-01-28 13:14:37 - Maps] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2015-01-28 13:30:38 - Maps] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

Comment: @JoMo ok... the other error is because you are using some java (byte code) jars in android which uses `Dalvik` ... not byte code, check your jars and you may need to get some jar for android

Comment: @Yazan  :) How do you check jars, and how do you get ones for android?

Comment: @not sure, but if you need some library , when you find it, try to download one compatible with android, not just java. somewhere i think there is a command to convert `jar` files to be android compatible.

Comment: @Yazan  Eclipse gave me these jars, so surely they are Android compatible. Boy, am I confused! Do you know anything about the JarJar executable files that are meant to help in these situations?(I tried running it without success)

Comment: @JoMo as a final sol, i would create a new project, just copy your classes to the new project, don't re import or include any jar files, you don't need to include other jars, just create new android project, and pick API from the list.i have never manually imported such jars (android.jar or map.jar)

Comment: @Yazan Hey, thanks for all your interest! I am going to try your sol..when you say "just copy your classes to the new project" do you mean literally only the .java,  xml layout classes and Manifest OR  do you mean everything within the present project folder i.e.  settings, assets, bin, gen, libs, res, src etc. ?

Comment: @JoMo no just all classes under /src, any layout, xml, values ... now if you use any library jars (other than android.jar and map.jar) you have to add them to the class path. **[make sure you create a new ANDROID project]** not just Java project. if other errors pops copy the needed files accordingly